# error with TFS in VS code: "Unable to validate the collection assuming 'DefaultCollection'"

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code

i trying to connect to TFS in VS code. 
i was install the Extension - "Visual Studio Team Services Extension for Visual Studio Code".
i turn the workspace to "local" and sign in Successfully.
and i add the root for the path in the "user settings" like this:

```
{
"tfvc.location": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\tf.exe",
"tfvc.restrictWorkspace": true,
"window.zoomLevel": 2,
```

}

but now when i try to run a command, like:

> Team: Associate work item

i geting the error:

> Unable to validate the collection assuming 'DefaultCollection'

any idea what the problem?
mayby i miss any step?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tested on my side, everything works as expected. Firstly make sure you have correctly set the [TFVC support](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md).

Based on the error message, seems it's related to the workspace. Make sure you have correctly mapped the workspace. Just try to remap the existing workspace or create a new workspace and map sources to a new local folder, then check that again.

If that still not work and you are sure that no any issues with the workspace, then just try to specify the **collection** and **team project name** in the `user settings` like this:

```
{
    "tfvc.location": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\tf.exe",
    "team.remoteUrl": "http://server:8080/tfs/collection",
    "team.teamProject": "TeamProjectName",
    "tfvc.restrictWorkspace": true,
    "window.zoomLevel": 2 
}
```